# Why am I not able to decrypt the data from database?

Tags: php, laravel

In this code I am using an AES256 algorithm for encryption and decryption and I am able to encrypt data, but unable to decrypt it from the database. Why? There is something wrong in this code. It shows me false in console. Basically i get error at:

`$decrypted=openssl_decrypt($parts[0], $this->AES_256_CBC, $this->encryption_key, 0,$this->iv);`

in this. But when I do in same function it work properly. Are there some issues in this code? If yes, then please help me.

```
public function add_users(Request $request){
    $users = new User();
    $users->name=$request->name;
    $users->email = $request->email;
    $users->password=$request->password;
    $users->role=$request->role;
    $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($users->name, $this->AES_256_CBC, $this->encryption_key, 0,$this->iv);
    $encrypted1 = openssl_encrypt($users->email, $this->AES_256_CBC, $this->encryption_key,  0, $this->iv);
    $encrypted2 = openssl_encrypt($users->password, $this->AES_256_CBC, $this->encryption_key, 0,$this->iv);
    $encrypted3 = openssl_encrypt($users->role, $this->AES_256_CBC, $this->encryption_key, 0,$this->iv);
    DB::insert('insert into users (name,email,password,role) values(?,?,?,?)',[$encrypted,$encrypted1,$encrypted2,$encrypted3]);
}


public function edit(Request $request){

    $id = $request->id;
    $user = User::where(['id' => $id])->get()->toArray();
    $data = $user[0]['name'];
    $data = $data . ':' . $this->iv;
    $parts = explode(':', $data);
    $decrypted=openssl_decrypt($parts[0], $this->AES_256_CBC, $this->encryption_key, 0,$this->iv);
    dd($decrypted);
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn’t you use Laravels built in encryption/decryption? https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/encryption#using-the-encrypter

Comment: I want to use AES algorithm.It is my project

Comment: The very first line of the encryption documentation says it uses AES_256_CBC, just like you are using in the example.

Comment: But i want to use my own logic in these algorithm

Comment: You are using the same key?

Comment: Then how to encrpyt and decrpyt the data

Comment: There is no1 to solve this problem